# How to display Google admob SmartBannerLandscape mode iOS correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am currently using a custom view from storyboard and place bannerView into the custom view. so I have been searching how to display smart banner landscape correctly. I added delegate to check whether I did receive and ads from them. however, this is what I got 'adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: Request Error: No ad to show.' Below is the code that I'm using to detect the orientation and display the ad based on the size. May I know do I have to fix the size of the custom view ?

```
override func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        self.bannerView?.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape

    } else {
        self.bannerView?.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
    }

}
```